# SSL installation on Tomcat - Certificate is not valid

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I have a java/angular application installed in a tomcat windows corp server.

The application is accessed remotely using http just fine.

Now I need to install ssl to it.

I already have the certificate from the certification authority and generated the mycert.jks file.

Then placed that file in the tomcat \conf folder and configured tomcat server.xml connector like this:

```
<Connector port="xxx" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100"
           minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="myalias"
           keystoreFile="conf\mycert.jks"
           keystorePass="mypass" />
```

Now when I access the application remotely (https://10.10.100.10/myapp), the application loads fine in the browser, but I'm getting a `Not secure - Certificate is not valid` message.

When I click the `Certificate is not valid` message it opens the certificate details.

The information there is correct (Issued To - Common Name, Validity Period...).

So it means the server can correctly find my certificate.

The validity period has not expired. So it is ok also.

The date/time on the server is also correct.

What else can it be?

UPDATE

Adding data seen when "Certificate is not valid" message is clicked on the browser:

```
Issued To
Common Name (CN)    mycn
Organization (O)    myorg
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>

Issued By
Common Name (CN)    mycn
Organization (O)    myorg
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>

Validity Period
Issued On   Tuesday, September 26, 2023 at 9:38:18AM
Expires On  Monday, December 25, 2023 at 9:38:18AM

Fingerprints
SHA-256 Fingerprint XX XX XX XX XX XX...
SHA-1 Fingerprint   XX XX XX XX XX XX...
```

UPDATE 2:

I tried it this other way, but still getting the same error message.

Generated the .jks using this command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myservername -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore myservername.jks -dname "CN=myservername, O=MyOrg, L=, ST=, C=" && keytool -certreq -alias myservername -file myservername.csr -keystore myservername.jks
```

It generated a myservername.csr file and a myservername.jks file.

Then, I ran this command

`keytool -list -keystore myservername.jks`

and got this result:

```
myservername, Oct 20, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxxxxxxx
```

Then I sent the myservername.csr file to the certificate authority and they sent me back this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I pasted that into a myservername.cer file.

I double click the myservername.cer and went to certificate path tab and I see this:
rootcertname > intermediatecertname > myservername

myservername is the alias I choose in the first command above.

Then I clicked rootcertname > view certificate > details > copy to file > next > Base 64 encoded x.509 (cer)

It generated rootcertname.cer

Then I clicked intermediatecertname > view certificate > details > copy to file > next > Base 64 encoded x.509 (cer)

It generated intermediatecertname.cer

Then I imported both certificates to the keystore like this:

```
keytool -keystore myservername.jks -import -alias root -trustcacerts -file rootcertname.cer
keytool -keystore myservername.jks -import -alias intermediate -trustcacerts -file intermediatecertname.cer
```

Then I ran this command again to list the certificates in the keystore:

```
keytool -list -keystore myservername.jks
```

and got this result:

```
intermediate, Oct 23, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxxx
root, Oct 23, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxx
myservername, Oct 20, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxxx
```

So it has the privatekey (generated in the first command above) plus the root and intermediate certificates from the Certification Authority.

Copied myservername.jks to Tomcat \conf folder.

Tomcat server.xml connector is configured as previously informed.

But when I access the application on the browser using https I still get the same error message:
`Not secure - Certificate is not valid`

IMPORTANT:
Noticed that when I click View Certificate in the Issuer name it says "myservername" (which is the private key alias). Instead, it should display the Certification Authority certificate name.

Comment: Is the whole certificate chain available in the keystore?

Comment: @Just another Java programmer Not sure what you exactly mean by chain. But when I run the cmd ```keytool -list -keystore mycert.jks```, it opens a lot of information about the cert (owner, issuer, certificate fingerprints with SHA codes, Signature algorithm name, Subject Public Key Algorithm, Alias name, validity period, CertificatePolicies, SubjectAlternativeName, SubjectKeyIdentifier...). Seems to be ok.

Comment: Is the certificate coming from a valid certification authority? This may be the issue..

Comment: @Joan What do you mean by valid and how to know it is valid? Is that a specific configuration that needs to be done? The certification authority is certainly a provider that can be trusted as it provides several certs for other of the corp apps.

Comment: Can you share the certificate information that you're seeing in the browser (The General TAB?

Comment: @Joan I updated the question adding what I see in the browser General Tab

Comment: It looks like it might be invalid because it's not *trusted*. Was it issued by an authority the browser already trusts? It looks like it's self-signed, which would mean no. Secure means encrypted *and* trusted.

Comment: @nitind How do I check if it was issued by an authority the browser trusts? Also, how do I check if it was self-signed?

Comment: if it is self-signed, the shown issuer of the cert should be self-signed or something like this. Regarding the browser: well, it depends on the used browser. e.g. in firefox I think they are visible with the url: about:preferences#privacy look for the subsection "Certificates" there should be a button "view certificates" which should list them.

Comment: @roediGERhard Looks like the certificate is indeed self-signed. I was using Chrome. Now opened it on Firefox which gave a better clue. It says: xx.xx.xxx.x uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT. View certificate.

Comment: there you have it. So either your proper certificate is not used by tomcat or...? btw: why do you use tomcat to do the ssl stuff? I always use an apache in front as reverse proxy to do the stuff.

Comment: @roediGERhard I added UPDATE 2 to the question with more details. Noted that the Issuer name is incorrect. It shows myservername (which is the private key alias) instead of the certification authority cetificate name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta: this is no longer ontopic, though years ago it was, and I've seen many similar Qs, but can't easily find a good dupe.

So close and yet ... not.

The canonical pure-Java sequence to get a cert-and-key for an SSL/TLS server, including an HTTPS server like Tomcat, is:

1A. generate keypair with `keytool -genkey[pair]`; this also generates a dummy self-signed certificate for the generated keypair and the 'dname' (subject name and also issuer name) you enter, plus some other parameters you could have specified but didn't (see below)

1B. create CSR with `keytool -certreq`

You did these correctly.

‌2. submit CSR to CA along with other information as needed (usually but not necessarily proof of domain 'ownership') and get back at least a server aka end-entity cert; usually the CA also supplies any needed root and intermediate aka 'chain' cert(s).

Your CA apparently didn't give you the chain, but when you opened it in cryptext.dll (which is the default action for doubleclick .cer on Windows) both the intermediate and root were found in your Windows store. It is common for an enterprise with an in-house CA and domain-joined or otherwise centrally-managed Windows workstations -- especially if the in-house CA is the one provided by Windows AD -- to 'push' their CA root to all machines; it is less common but possible to push the intermediate(s), or that(those) might be cached from previous accesses by this machine to (intranet) server(s) using in-house cert(s).

Thus you dealt with this correctly.

3A. `keytool -import[cert]` the root and intermediate(s) (if any), from the top down, to the *same* keystore under *different* (unique) alias(es)

3B. `keytool -import[cert]` the server cert to the same keystore and same alias as used in 1A and 1B. This replaces the dummy self-signed cert created in 1A by the CA-issued one and also builds its certification path using the cert(s) imported in 3A.

**You did 3A but not 3B**; as a result the dummy self-signed cert created in 1A remains in place and is used, and since it indeed is not valid it is correctly rejected by the browser. **You need to do 3B** (and bounce your Tomcat if it is already running).

A variant method is that some CAs provide the end-entity cert PLUS the chain cert(s) in a package using either a PKCS7 format usually labelled p7b or p7c, or a simpler PEM-sequence format. Yours didn't, but given you have the chain certs in your Windows store the 'cert export wizard' can create the PKCS7 format; just select the P7B button and tick the 'include all certs' box. In this case 3A and 3B can be replaced by a single step:

3'. import the p7b/c package or PEM-sequence of (all) certs to the same keystore and alias as 1A and 1B. This both replaces the dummy self-signed cert and builds the certification path from the input, thereby ending up with essentially the same result.

Finally, note that SSL/TLS certificates are *usually* issued as valid for a domain-style name or set of such names, not an IPaddress. Public CAs require the name be a *real* domain name i.e. registered in public DNS, but inhouse CAs like the one you used can accept other names if they want, like NetBIOS names. A cert *can* allow both name(s) and IPaddress(es); look at the Subject Alternative Name field in the cryptext.dll viewer or `keytool -printcert` or `keytool -list -v` on the keystore.

If your CA gave you an IPaddress-capable cert `https://<ipaddr>` will work, but if it gave you a name-only cert you must use `https://<name>` and not `https://<ipaddr>`.

Comment: Perfect! It worked very well. I executed this cmd for step 3B: ```keytool -keystore myservername.jks -import -alias myservername -trustcacerts -file myservername.cer``` The rest is the same of Update 2. With that it all worked. I also tried the alternative way you suggested (exporting the .p7b file). It also worked. Answer accepted. Many thanks for the solution and detailed explanation. Really helpful.